# うちに spot the difference

Tags: grammar

うちに has two rather confusingly different meanings.

One is in line with its never seen kanji form. Whilst. Do x whilst y.

Another means do x before y's situation changes.

The two are quite different as to when x should be done. 
Is there a way to spot which is meant?

Comment: Short answer: look at the context.  They are not that confusing - do you have a text book and a few model examples? BTW: There is one other use which is a slightly different; to describe a change that happen while something was in progress that was not of the main actor's volition.

Comment: I see "while" and "before the situation changes" as basically the same thing. Or at least while it's in present tense.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think those meanings sound very different, but if you were to give some examples we would be better able to address your question.

～うちに can be used in a number of (grammatical) situations, and in almost all of those it can be understood in English<sup>1</sup> as "while".

> 考えているうちに分からなくなった。
>   *Kangaete iru uchi ni wakaranaku natta.*
>   (While thinking about it, I got lost.)

However, **when ～うちに follows a negative** it can be understood in English as "before".

> 雨が降らないうちにテニスをしてきます。
>   *Ame ga furanai uchi ni tenisu o shite kimasu.*
>   (I'll go and play tennis (and come back) before it rains.)

Additionally, when ～うちに is preceded by something for which the beginning and ending is certain, ～間【あいだ】に can be substituted.

> 子供が学校に行っているうちに／間に本を読みます。
>   *Kodomo ga gakkou ni itte iru uchi ni / aida ni hon o yomimasu.*
>   (I read books while my child is away at school.)

I hope this answers your question. If not, I am more than willing to expand it.

---

Notes:
<sup>1</sup> Though as a matter of personal opinion, I don't believe this is the best way to understand things in a foreign language.

---

References:
Makino, Seiichi and Tsutsui, Michio. "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar". Japan Times, 1994.

Answer (score 5):

For example,

> Do x whilst y
>   [明]{あか}るい**うちに**(≒明るい[間]{あいだ}に)[帰]{かえ}ってきなさい。(Come back while it's bright)
>   [温]{あたた}かい**うちに**(≒温かい間に)食べなさい。(Eat while it's warm)
>   子どもが[寝]{ね}ている**うちに**(≒寝ている間に)[洗濯]{せんたく}します。(I do the laundry while the child is sleeping)

can be rephrased:

> Do x before ys situation changes
>   [暗]{くら}くなら**ないうちに**(≒暗くなる[前]{まえ}に)帰ってきなさい。(Come back before it gets dark)
>   [冷]{さ}め**ないうちに**(≒冷める前に)食べなさい。(Eat before it gets cold)
>   子どもが[起]{お}き**ないうちに**(≒起きる前に)洗濯します。(I do the laundry before the child wakes up)

(Use a negative form for the latter format.)

Comment: In my opinion, the second case is best thought of as equivalent to the English "while" as well: `While it is not (yet) dark, come back.`